# Linq to Querystring substringof

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a asp.net web api with linktoquerystring: [link](http://linqtoquerystring.net/index.html)

Asp.net controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[LinqToQueryable]
[Route("")]
public IQueryable<ApplicationViewModel> All()
{
    return _applicationRepository.All();
}
```

Api url:

```
http://localhost:61036/api/customers?$filter=substringof('s', name);
```

Problem: api returns:

```
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the problem, wrong documentation [doc](http://linqtoquerystring.net/syntax.html):

```
substringof /Customers?$filter=substringof(‘Alfreds’, CompanyName) eq true
```

but it has to be

```
substringof /Customers?$filter=substringof(‘Alfreds’,CompanyName) eq true
```

so no space between 'Alfreds' and CompanyName